# How to print multiple non-consecutive values from a list with Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have created a list and want to choose a handful of items to print from the list. Below, I'd just like to print out "bear" at index 0 and "kangaroo" at index 3. My syntax is not correct:

```
>>> animals = ['bear', 'python', 'peacock', 'kangaroo', 'whale', 'platypus']
>>> print (animals[0,3])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    print (animals[0,3]) TypeError: list indices must be integers
>   or slices, not tuple

I tried with a space between the indexes but it still gives an error:

```
>>> print (animals[0, 3])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    print (animals[0, 3]) TypeError: list indices must be
>   integers or slices, not tuple

I am able to print a single value or a range from 0-3, for example, with:

```
>>> print (animals [1:4])
['python', 'peacock', 'kangaroo']
```

How can I print multiple non-consecutive list elements?

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. Seems like a legit question to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To pick arbitrary items from a list you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter    
>>> print(*itemgetter(0, 3)(animals))
bear kangaroo
>>> print(*itemgetter(0, 5, 3)(animals))
bear platypus kangaroo
```

Comment: This will fail if you pass a single index to `itemgetter`, since it would return the value at the index directly without enclosing it in a tuple.

Comment: What is the purpose of the star? Trying this example with the star produces a syntax error for me, but when I remove it the code works.

Comment: @Rawrcasm Probably because you're using Python 2.7?

Answer (score 9):

Slicing with a tuple as in `animals[0,3]` is not supported for Python's `list` type. If you want certain arbitrary values, you will have to index them separately.

```
print(animals[0], animals[3])
```

Answer (score 6):

`list(animals[x] for x in (0,3))` is the subset you want. Unlike numpy arrays, native Python lists do not accept lists as indices.

You need to wrap the generator expression in `list` to print it because it does not have an acceptable `__str__` or `__repr__` on its own. You could also use `str.join` for an acceptable effect: `', '.join(animals[x] for x in (0,3))`.

Answer (score 2):

Python's list type does not support that by default. Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by range(start, stop, step).

```
class slice(start, stop[, step])

>>>animals[0:5:2]
['bear', 'peacock', 'whale']
```

Either creating a subclass to implement by yourself or getting specified values indirectly. e.g.:

```
>>>map(animals.__getitem__, [0,3])
['bear', 'kangaroo']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(animals[0] + " " + animals[3] + " " + ...)
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers and post a short explanation why this works.  Also, how is this different from the other answers posted a few years ago?

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. Care to explain?