# Printing python specific list indexes using for loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list `l1 =[1,56,67,79,90,47,08,56,79,84,76,79,68,]`

Now, I want to print indices 4,6,9,10 alone using a loop

I tried:

```
for i in l1:
    Print(i[4]..)
```

But it says: `int is not subscriptable`

Comment: Why do you need the for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print multiple non-consecutive values from a list with Python 3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435569/how-to-print-multiple-non-consecutive-values-from-a-list-with-python-3-5-1)

Comment: It was the task given bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to loop over all items in the list by the indexes you could do something like this:

```
l1 =[1,56,67,79,90,47,8,56,79,84,76,79,68]
for i in range(len(l1)):
   if i in (4, 6, 9, 10):
      print(l1[i])
```

that being said, this is not the most efficient thing

Comment: Yeah this works too although my only comment on this approach is that it is better to use a named list than use a tuple for maintainability,

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is for a homework and so you want to use loops for this.
When you say `i in l1` each element `i` is an `int` and so it won't work to index it.

If you are trying to specifically print elements in indexes 4, 6, 9, 10 then you need to put these in a list and iterate over these. So for ex:

```
l1 =[1,56,67,79,90,47,08,56,79,84,76,79,68,]
to_print = [4, 6, 9, 10] # So if you want to print other/more index positions then modify this. Note that you may want to do a length check too before using these indexes as is.
for i in to_print:
    print(l1[i])
```

Comment: Tkz alot got it helped me

Comment: How to do tht i m new here

Comment: Oh on the left side of the answer below the score you'll see a check mark. Click on it to mark as accepted.